# How to enforce a monotonic answer in a single feature in a Binary classification problem

Tags: classification, random-forest

I am trying to use sklearn Random forest to predict the probability of win/lose in a card game. There are 4 features in my data set. Feature $X_4$ is the hand strength of the player and y (the winning probability) is monotonically increasing in the hand strength. Thus I have a cutoff decision: for every combination of the first three features $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ there is a Threshold $T$ such that, for $X_4 > T$, play Right, otherwise play Left.

The prediction isn't monotonic,  that is, for some $(X_1,X_2,X_3, X_4=x')$ the predicted label is $1$ however for $(X_1,X_2,X_3, X_4=x'')$ where $x''>x'$ the predicted label is $0$.

**How can I enforce this monotonicity?**

Should I use a different classifier?  is DecisionTreeClassifier better suit this problem? 
my data labels are unbalanced at 65:35

Comment: I’m not aware of a way to do this using sklearn unless you want to write the class yourself. However the xgboost library supports monotonicity in features.

Comment: You can use logistic regression, maybe representant $X_4$ with a (monotone) spline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logistic regression + bucketing produced a monotonic answer.